# Android running thread in background

Tags: android, multithreading, alarmmanager

I am developing an app that has in a database a set of times. The app has to run a thread at those times (5 minutes before each) each day.
The way I'm doing it now is running a thread in the background every half-minute and checking if the time now matches a time in the DB. This is not working and I'm afraid the thread stops running after a while (I have a notification which should come up each time, and it is not happening). What I'm guessing is happening is that each time the phone turn off it screen, my app is stopped. How can I resolve this? I heard something about AlarmManager but failed to know how to use it.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this example http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/ for alarm manager

Comment: I can do that, but then there will be a notification shot every half minute and the user wont be very happy with this... I already made a service that has startForeground() and there is a running notification

Comment: @JaviDorfsman Just set the alarm times to the times in the DB... Don't try to have a continually running thread. There's no need.

Comment: @kabuko can you give me and example of how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "postDelay" method? http://binarybuffer.com/2012/07/executing-scheduled-periodic-tasks-in-android
It able you to run some code every "X" miliseconds.